# Faster solution for groupby and aggregate in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe looking like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"id": [1,1,1,2,3,3], "s1": [4,np.nan,np.nan,1,1,5], "s2": [14,np.nan,19,np.nan,18,19]})

    id  s1  s2
0   1   4.0 14.0
1   1   NaN NaN
2   1   NaN 19.0
3   2   1.0 NaN
4   3   1.0 18.0
5   3   5.0 19.0
```

My goal is to transform it in a way that the result looks like this

```
    s1          s2
id      
1   [4.0]       [14.0, 19.0]
2   [1.0]       [0]
3   [1.0, 5.0]  [18.0, 19.0]
```

That means i want to group by the field "id", aggregate all the other columns together to a list (and as a fallback create a list with zero if values are NaN for that combination)

My current pure Pandas approach is super slow for larger dataframes (> 100k rows and ~100 columns).

```
def _aggregate_listwise(x):
    return list(x.dropna()) if not x.isnull().all() else [0]

df.groupby("id").agg(lambda x: _aggregate_listwise(x))
```

Is there a nice pythonic way to speed up my solution a bit? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Probably insignificant, but why do you wrap that perfectly fine function in a lambda instead of just `agg(_aggregate_listwise)`?

Comment: Yes also true thought it only helped a little ;)

Comment: How about being an optimist and do `agg(lambda x: list(x.dropna()) or [0])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `stack` then `unstack`, however, for the object column agg, the running time always longer than usual.

```
out = df.set_index('id').stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(list).unstack(fill_value=[0])
Out[617]: 
            s1            s2
id                          
1        [4.0]  [14.0, 19.0]
2        [1.0]           [0]
3   [1.0, 5.0]  [18.0, 19.0]
```

Comment: Nice thanks a lot! Speed up by 5-10 times. Cool idea with stack/unstack